# MATLAB - Find Frequency of Transfer Function Corresponding to a Magnitude

Tags: matlab

Given a transfer function `H(s)`, I plot the `bode(H)`. Now I want to get the frequency at which the magnitude equals a specific number.

Is this possible?

Comment: use `find` with some threshold condition? `find(A<A0+dA & A>A0-dA)` ...

Comment: This is a transfer function, not a vector! I can't use `find` on it.

Comment: It says you can't use find on a system of type ss

Comment: see my answer shortly...

Comment: @Jubobs, thanks dude! I'll start using that site for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's how to do this using `find` with the handles `bode` function gives you. Let's start with the following example:

```
H = tf([1 0.1 7.5],[1 0.12 9 0 0]);
[mag,phase,wout]=bode(H);
```

then use find as follows:

```
thr = 1e-2;
ind = find(mag>0.47-thr & mag<0.47+thr)
```

and the frequency for that magnitude (0.47) will be:

```
wout(ind)
```